# Comparing $S_3$-coinvariants of symmetric and exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-groups, invariant-theory

Consider (over $\mathbf C$) the exterior algebra $\tilde A=\Lambda(x,y,z)$ on three generators, i.e. non-commutative polynomials with the relation that $xy=–yx$, and similarly for the others, as well as the symmetric algebra $A=S(x,y,z)=\mathbf C[x,y,z]$. There is an obvious action of the symmetric group $S_3$ on both. I want to understand the respective coinvariant algebraas $\tilde A_{S_3}=\tilde A/(\tilde A^{S_3})_+$, and $A_{S_3}$ similarly..

**What I expect to happen**: proposition 0.4 in [this document](http://ms.unimelb.edu.au/~ortizo/The%20Coinvariant%20Algebra.pdf) makes me expect that $\dim_\mathbf C A_{S_3} = 6$ (although $A$ is not finite dimensional).

**What I actually computed**: First for the exterior algebra. $ (\tilde A^{S_3})_+=(x+y+z, xyz)$;
the missing elementary symmetric polynomial is inverted by a simple reflection and hence is not contained in the invariants. The naive approach to a basis of the quotient is to check which of $1,x,y,z,xy,yz,xz,xyz$ (which are a basis for $\tilde A$) becomes linearly dependent.

- $z = -x-y$
- $xy = -y^2-zy=-zy$ by $y$ times the relation $x+y+z=0$
- $yz = -z^2-xz=-xz$
- $xz = -x^2-xy=-xy$,
- hence $xy,xy$ and $xz$ are linearly dependent.

The quotient thus has a basis $\langle 1,x,y,xy\rangle$.

For the symmetric algebra, $A^{S_3}=(x+y+z, xy+yz+xz, x^2+y^2+z^2, xyz)$. Then $A_{S_3}$ has a basis $\langle 1,x,y,x^2,y^2\rangle$. This can be obtained by observing that the following naive basis vectors are linearly dependent:

- $z = -x - y$
- $z^2 = -x^2 - y^2$
- $z^2 = (x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$, hence $x^2+y^2=-xy$
- $xz=-x^2-xy=-x^2+x^2+y^2=y^2$
- $yz=x^2$
- $x^3=xyz=0$

and all others of degree 3 similarly.

**Question**: Have I calculated wrong, or should I expect a different dimension? Is the theorem valid also for infinite-dimensional vector spaces? Is there a similar theorem for the exterior algebra?

**What I am actually after**: I want to compare $(A_{S_3})^s$ and $(\tilde A_{S_3})^s$ for $s$ the simple reflection that interchanges $x$ and $y$. From the above bases I obtain:

- $(A_{S_3})^s=(x+y) \ni xy$ with $(x+y)^2=xy$
- $(\tilde A_{S_3})^s=(x+y, xy)$ with $(x+y)^2=0$.

What astonishes me is that they are nearly the same: isomorphic as vector spaces (both have basis $\langle 1,x+y,xy\rangle$), but not as algebras. However, I do not trust in my calculations, so: Are both actually isomorphic (as algebras)?

Comment: are you sure $xyz$ is invariant ?

Comment: You mean in $\tilde A$? You're right, it isn't. This enlarges the respective coinvariants, but gives no difference to the last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation in the original question is correct as far as I can see, but you should have expected a different dimension (although I would not have been able to immediately predict it to be 4). The point is: proposition 0.4 from the paper you mention talks about this construction for the **symmetric** algebra, but you use the exterior algebra, which already has a much smaller number of dimensions to begin with.

In the bonus question you *should* expect dimension 6 by proposition 0.4 so something is missing in your basis for $A_{S_3}$. I'm not sure what it is. x^3 perhaps? Also it seems that in the symmetric case $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ deserves a place in your list of generators of $(A^{S_3})$ and perhaps there are others.

Comment: I admit that my original question was really dumb. However, for the symmetric algebra (which is infinite dimensional), do you know whether the proposition mentioned still holds?

Comment: I have (tried to) recalculate(d), and have updated my question, also according to what I'm actually after. Maybe you are so kind to have a look at it.

Comment: This sounds stupid, but the reason we know that the proposition holds for the symmetric algebra is that the document you took it from proves it for the symmetric algebra. Note that the finite dimensional space $V$ the document is talking about is $\mathbb{C}^3$ in you case, so also finite dimensional.

Comment: More generally speaking: the infinite-dimensionality of $S(V)$ is 'not too bad' because it is infinite dimensional in a very controlled way. For one thing, it is a graded vector space and all homogeous pieces in the grading are finite dimensional. Secondly it is generated as an algebra by finitely many elements. Thirdly, in many interesting contexts the contribution of the symmetric algebra factors over a finite dimensional quotient - your example is exactly an example of this last phenomenon

Comment: Are you sure that $x^2y$ etc are all zero?

Comment: I am uncertain: I see $x^2y=-xz^2=y^2z$ and $xy^2=-yz^2=x^2z$, and I can relate them by $x^2y=(-y^2-z^2)y=-z^2y$, but then all of the six are the same and hence they must have been already contained in $A^{S_3}$.

Comment: It seem they are not all six the same: 3 are the same and the other 3 are the negative of this one element. This would mean any of the two equivalence classes could be taken as the sixth basis element predicted by the proposition

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, and I managed to calculate this correctly finally. Thank you!